# solve $-2y'(t)=y(1/t)$ spot my mistake

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

solve $-2y'(t)=y(1/t)$ spot my mistake:
$$\begin{align}
y'(z)&=-\frac1{t^2} y'(1/t)\\
-\frac{2y'(1/t)}{t^2}&=y(1/t)\\
y'(1/t)-\frac{t^2}2 y(1/t)&=0\\
(y(1/t)e^{-t^3/6})'&=0\\
(y(1/t)e^{-t^3/6})&=c\\
y(1/t)&=ce^{t^3/6}\\
\end{align}$$
thanks

Comment: is it an exercise from a book Peru ? Which one ?

Comment: hello again @LostInSpace =) . I wish I knew, it was taken from a test.

Comment: You should have a second differential $y''(z)$ not y'(z)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-2y'(t)=y(1/t)$$
Differentiate both sides. You end with a Cauchy-Euler differential eqaution.
$$-2y''(t)=-\frac 1 {t^2} y'(1/t) 
$$
But we also have from original equation
$$-2y'(1/t)=y(t) \implies y'(1/t)=-\frac 12y(t)$$
So that:
$$\implies -2y''(t)=\frac 1 {2t^2} y(t)$$
$$ 4t^2y''(t)+ y(t)=0$$
This is Cauchy-Euler's differential equation.
$$\implies y(t)=c_1\sqrt t +c_2 \ln|t|\sqrt t$$
Plug this in the initial differential equation and find $c_1,c_2$

---

It's not clear what you did in the first step. Plus you have a z variable. Did you differentiate both sides Peru ?

Comment: amazing! when I get a y(1/t) term, is there any way to get rid of it beside substitute it on other equation?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that ...Well if there is one I don't know it @peru

Comment: how did you know that you should take the derivative ?@LostInspace

Comment: With some DE it works to differentiate...@peru. I dind't invent it it's well known

Comment: well it's my first time I see that somebody uses this trick =) @LostInspace.

Answer (score -1):

The operation of taking the inverse applied twice leads back to the original number, $(t^{-1})^{-1}=t$. There are other similar exercises based on the same principle that use the negation operation, $-(-t)=t$. The given equation connects value and derivative at such a conjugate pair of points $(t,t^{-1})$.

To get back to the framework of ODE, where all values and derivatives that are connected in the equation are taken at one single point, consider a state vector where these two values are both assigned to the same time $t$, $t\mapsto(x(t),y(t))=(y(1/t),y(t))$, using the "conjugate" function $x(t)=y(1/t)$.

The derivative of the second component is known, $$-2y'(t)=x(t).$$ The derivative of the first component can be computed similarly to what you tried (this is the part where what you did went slightly wrong), you should get the equation
$$
\implies x'(t)=-\frac{y'(1/t)}{t^2}=\frac{y(t)}{2t^2} ~~~ \text{ (using $-2y'(1/t)=y(t)$)}.
$$
Now the vector valued system is complete and is a normal ODE system, all functions and derivatives are evaluated at the same time $t$. Proceed with the solution method of your choice.